# Is there a way to draw over erased area created via PIXI.BLEND_MODES.ERASE mode using a Graphics object in pixijs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js

I've been trying to introduce some drawing functions to my app where user can draw and erase some areas in the canvas using mouse press and drag. My current idea is to use two separate graphics objects, one for the brush, one for the eraser, where eraser graphics is set to ERASE blend mode to erase the drawn pixels. However, the problem of this approach is that, once the areas are erased, there is no way to redraw over them as the pixels are deleted permanently from the canvas. So, unless the erase graphics itself is updated somehow, the erased area is always there. And this is certainly not good for my drawing and editing purpose.

A eraser seems like a simple enough problem, but somehow I can't find a good solution to it. Does anyone have some experiences with this? Any help is very much appreciated!

```
import { Graphics, Point, BLEND_MODES } from 'pixi.js'
class ClearableGraphics extends Container {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.pen = new Graphics()
    this.eraser = new Graphics()
    this.pen.lineStyle({ width: 8, color: '0x000000', cap: 'round' })
    this.eraser.lineStyle({ width: 8, color: '0x000000', cap: 'round' })
    this.pen.blendMode = BLEND_MODES.SRC_OVER
    this.eraser.blendMode = BLEND_MODES.ERASE
    this.addChild(this.pen)
    this.addChild(this.eraser)
    this.points = []
  }

  public draw(pt: { x: number; y: number }, mode: 'pen' | 'eraser' = 'pen') {
    if (this.points.length === 0) {
      const current = this.convertLocal(pt)
      this[mode].moveTo(current.x, current.y)
      // offsets a little to trigger line cap
      this[mode].lineTo(current.x + 0.01, current.y + 0.01)
    } else {
      const current = this.convertLocal(pt)
      const last = this.convertLocal(this.points[this.points.length - 1])
      this[mode].moveTo(last.x, last.y)
      this[mode].lineTo(current.x, current.y)
    }
    this.points.push(pt)
  }

  public convertLocal(pt: IPixiFreeDrawPt): IPoint {
    return this.parent.toLocal(new Point(pt.x, pt.y))
  }
}
```

So far, I also have tried using image mask and renderTexture, but I can't get them to work either.

Answer (score 0):

You could paint/erase into a `RenderTexture`.

I am assuming you are using the default [Renderer](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Renderer.html#render) i.e. WebGL.

```
const renderTexture = RenderTexture.create({ width: 800, height: 600 });
const sprite = Sprite.from(renderTexture);
app.stage.addChild(sprite);

const pen = new Graphics;
const eraser = new Graphics;
pen.lineStyle({ width: 8, color: '0x000000', cap: 'round' })
eraser.lineStyle({ width: 8, color: '0x000000', cap: 'round' })
pen.blendMode = BLEND_MODES.SRC_OVER
eraser.blendMode = BLEND_MODES.ERASE

// draw with pen, then:
app.renderer.render(pen, { renderTexture, clear: false }); 

// draw with eraser, then:
app.renderer.render(eraser, { renderTexture, clear: false });
```